# How to convert an object type to two dimensional array in lodash?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object, lodash

I need to convert an object type to an array of different objects in order to display several tables in my angular project.

Below is my object:

```
let myObject = {
  internalValue:{city:"Paris", country:"France", pinCode:12345}, 
  originalValue:{city:"Nantes", country:"France", pinCode:34567}, 
  score:{city:10, country:100, pinCode:45}
};
```

Expected Array

```
[
  [
    {detail:"Paris", label:"internalValue"},
    {detail:"Nantes", label:"originalValue"},
    {detail:10, label:"score"}
  ],
  [
    {detail:"France", label:"internalValue"},
    {detail:"France", label:"originalValue"},
    {detail:100, label:"score"}
  ],
  [
    {detail:12345, label:"internalValue"},
    {detail:34567, label:"originalValue"},
    {detail:45, label:"score"}
  ]
]
```

My code

```
let tableData:any;
tableData = _.transform(myObject, result, value, key)=>{
  let retValue:any;
  _.forIn(value, (v,k)=> {
    let tempArr:Array<any>;
    let tempObj:any = {};
    tempObj.detail= v;
    tempObj.label=key;
    tempArr.push(tempObj);
    retValue.push(tempArr);
  })
  result = [...retValue];
  return result;
},[]);
```

Stuck here for the next set of loops.

Answer (score 2):

Lodash isn't really required here. You could do this by using the `Object.keys` and `Object.values` to iterate over the properties of the objects.

Here you initially get the required keys (`city`, `country`, `pinCode`) from 1st value in the object and iterate over.
Below is an example:

```js
let myObject = {
  internalValue:{city:"Paris", country:"France", pinCode:12345}, 
  originalValue:{city:"Nantes", country:"France", pinCode:34567}, 
  score:{city:10, country:100, pinCode:45}
};

let keys = Object.keys(myObject);
let values = Object.values(myObject);

let result = Object.keys(values[0]).map((_, i) => {
  return keys.map(key => {
    return {detail: myObject[key][Object.keys(values[0])[i]], label: key};
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of keys you wish to extract (`fields` in the example). Use `Object.entries()` on the original object to get an array of `[key, value]` pairs (`entries` in the example). Now map the `fields`, and map the `entries` to create an array for each field:

```js
const fields = ['city', 'country', 'pinCode'];

const fn = obj => {
  const entries = Object.entries(obj);

  return fields.map(field => 
    entries.map(([label, val]) => ({
      detail: val[field],
      label
    }))
  );
};

const myObject = {
  internalValue:{city:"Paris", country:"France", pinCode:12345}, 
  originalValue:{city:"Nantes", country:"France", pinCode:34567}, 
  score:{city:10, country:100, pinCode:45}
};

const result = fn(myObject);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Super thanks Ori

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can achieve this using lodash:

```js
let myObject = {
  internalValue:{city:"Paris", country:"France", pinCode:12345}, 
  originalValue:{city:"Nantes", country:"France", pinCode:34567}, 
  score:{city:10, country:100, pinCode:45}
};

const toDetails = (obj, keys = _.chain(obj).values().map(_.keys).first().value()) => {
   // OR keys = Object.keys(Object.values(obj)[0])

    return keys.map(key => {
        return _.chain(obj)
        .mapValues(key)
        .map((detail, label) => ({ detail, label }))
        .value();
    });
};

const explicit = toDetails(myObject, ["city", "country", "pinCode"]);
console.log("explicit", explicit);

const implicit = toDetails(myObject);
console.log("implicit", implicit);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```